# How to generate a random alphanumeric string of a custom length in java?

Tags: java, string, random

What is the most simple way? Minimizing any imports.

This one is good:

```
String str = Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
```

But it's not perfect, for example it complicates with custom length.

Also an option: How to make this String unique?

Comment: Why don't you use string-handling functions? Just generate a random character in your desired range, in a loop, and keep concatenating it onto the string you're building. Also, why do you want to minimize imports?

Comment: There are no prizes for minimizing imports. It doesn't affect the time it takes to run, or even really the time to compile.

Comment: @hexafraction, yes, you are right, your method is rational.
DanielM. thanks, I will notice that.
But question is likely applied puzzle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a String of the characters which can be included in the string:

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

Generate an integer using the Random class and use it to get a random character from the String.

```
Random random = new Random();
alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(alphabet.length()));
```

Do this n times, where n is your custom length, and append the character to a String.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    builder.append(/* The generated character */);
}
```

Together, this could look like:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

public String generateString(int length) {
    Random random = new Random();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        builder.append(ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from commons-lang. If you don't wish to import, check out its source.